# Unable to access particular elements in HTML doc (using HTML Agility)

Tags: c#, html

I'm working on a C# project that requires scraping certain information from a website, so I'm using HTMLAgilityPack to help me with this. I'm very new to this sort of thing and I've run into a wall where I'm unable to retrieve certain elements from my loaded HTML document.

Previously, I've been able to retrieve swaths of nodes by specifying their contents as such:

```
 var importantLinks = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
            .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("href", "").Contains("details"))
```

Now, with a particular series of nodes, I'm unable to access them even with a very specific identifier.

[image]

I want to access the inner text of these links, but can't seem to. I've tried to search for them by specifying that their class contains "image", "image-list", etc, but they are never located. I've also tried just searching for their parent using its id, and then extracting its children, which didn't work either.

Being new to this, I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious.

Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

try this example, it could help i think from [C-Sharp Corner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9b86d4/getting-started-with-html-agility-pack/)

```
HtmlDocument document2 = new HtmlDocument();  
document2.Load(@"C:\Temp\sample.txt");  
   
HtmlNode[] nodes = document2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a").Where(x=>x.InnerHtml.Contains("div2")).ToArray();  
foreach (HtmlNode item in nodes)  
{  
    Console.WriteLine(item.InnerHtml);  
}
```

with HTML code :

```
<html>  
<head>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <div id="div1">  
        <a href="div1-a1">Link 1 inside div1</a>  
        <a href="div1-a2">Link 2 inside div1</a>  
    </div>  
    <a href="a3">Link 3 outside all divs</a>      
    <div id="div2">  
        <a href="div2-a1">Link 1 inside div2</a>  
        <a href="div2-a2">Link 2 inside div2</a>  
    </div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: It still skips over these trying that. The only difference I can see is that they reference javascript, but I don't know if that matters.